# Receiving None as a result of a function

Tags: python, html, nonetype

Sorry for the newbie question, but I am trying to create a website in HTML using data from a CSV file, and using python to generate it. One function im trying to use is:

```
def html_table(heading1, data1):
    print("""<table>       
        <tr>
        <th>""" + str(heading1) + "</th><td>")
    for i in data1:
        print(str(i) + "</td><td>")
    print("""</td>
    </tr>
    </table>""")
```

I put in a string as a heading name, and use a list as the data. When I print it on python it seems to print exactly how I want it, however when I open the html, it reads it as NoneType. This is what python prints out (with my values):

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Financial Year</th><td>
<td>1981–82</td>
<td>1982–83</td>
<td>1983–84</td>
<td>1984–85</td>
<td>1985–86</td>
<td>1986–87</td>
<td>1987–88</td>
<td>1988–89</td>
<td>1989–90</td>
</tr>
    </table>
```

etc...My question is why my html is not reading the second chunk of code as string?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: [Jinja2](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/dev/) is an excellent templating library for this kind of problem.

Answer (score 1):

That's because your function is returning nothing. It is only printing stuff.

You want to `return` that string not `print` it:

```
def html_table(heading1, data1):
   return """<table>
    <tr>
        <th>""" + str(heading1) + "</th><td>"
```

Comment: How do you suggest I incorporate the for loop into the return statement/s as well?

Comment: make a new variable - call it `html` or something - and then just use `+=` to add the new pieces on wherever you are using `print` right now - then at the end, `return html`

Comment: @JoshGregory Can also use the `yield` keyword and return a generator

Comment: @domoarrigato This seemed to fix the problem! Thanks for help guys.